# why is line-height 100% in html email boilerplate

Tags: html, email, boilerplate, css

in the [html email boilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com), there is a #backgroundTable id given to the wrapper. the line height property is set to 100% in the head, which ends up making all the text in the email start to overlap with each other

```
#backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}
```

why would they do this? it doesn't seem to enhance the email.

Comment: check out their GNARLY FEATURES section, it explains a little bit as to why it has what it has in it.  If that doesn't help then I'd recommend sending them feedback and ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

From the website you linked to:

```
.ExternalClass, ... {
      line-height: 100%;
 } /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing.  
 More on that: http://www.emailonacid.com/forum/viewthread/43/ */
```

Comment: but the line-height:100% is also in the backgroundTable, which wraps around the whole email.

Comment: I've just been looking into this line too and I've found `line-height: normal` works and looks better (not so squished).  So I use that instead.